# Curly braces in fancyvrb

Tags: formatting, braces, fancyvrb

I am convinced that I have seen this on here before, but I am unable to find it.

I am putting some code into a LaTeX document and I wish to add syntax colour to it. I have done this using fancyvrb and `\textcolor{}{}`. Unfortunately I am now not having tt style curly braces where I need them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\Verb[fontseries=b]!foo[{a,b},c]=a+b+c!
\Verb[fontseries=b,commandchars=\\\{\}]!foo[\{\textcolor{blue}{a},\textcolor{blue}{b}\},\textcolor{red}{c}]=a+b+c!

\end{document}
```

[image: Those braces are not right!]

Those braces are not right!

Comment: LaTeX says ``Font shape `OMS/cmtt/b/n' undefined using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 12.``. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` seems to work.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik fabulous thank you, this is not the solution I had before (which I have forgotten) but it is certainly much easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile the example LaTeX says:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmtt/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 9.
```

because the `OMS` encoding doesn't have that glyph in `tt` shape, so LaTeX falls back to `cmsy`.

You, for instance, switch the encoding to `T1` using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\Verb[fontseries=b]!foo[{a,b},c]=a+b+c!

\Verb[fontseries=b,commandchars=\\\{\}]!foo[\{\textcolor{blue}{a},\textcolor{blue}{b}\},\textcolor{red}{c}]=a+b+c!

\end{document}
```